# Shopify - Create Notice On Update Version Shopify Theme

Tags: themes, shopify

I want to create a notice for the new version on Shopify before customers install it like this below:

[image: link for image]

Does anyone know how to create this notice on Shopify or suggest me the keyword so I can search?

Answer (score 0):

Are you a theme developer?
You want to show your clients that there is a new version?
I believe that the notice shows automatically when you publish the new version to the Shopify theme store.
Is that not the case?
If not, then I believe the note will only show when the user clicks on the 'version' button.
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/themes/managing-themes/updating-themes#manual-updates